# Amount of time elapsed during time period

Tags: sql

I have the table:

```
+--------+------+------------+
| id     | type | timestamp  |
+--------+------+------------+
| 927061 |  573 | 1520284933 |
| 927062 |  573 | 1520284933 |
| 927063 |  573 | 1520284933 |
| 927064 |  573 | 1520284933 |
| 927347 |  573 | 1520285483 |
| 928796 |  573 | 1520287665 |
| 928799 |  573 | 1520287672 |
| 928801 |  573 | 1520287676 |
| 928802 |  573 | 1520287680 |
| 928806 |  573 | 1520287684 |
| 928821 |  573 | 1520287735 |
| 928822 |  573 | 1520287735 |
| 928823 |  573 | 1520287735 |
| 928824 |  573 | 1520287735 |
| 928825 |  573 | 1520287735 |
| 928826 |  573 | 1520287735 |
| 928827 |  573 | 1520287736 |
| 928828 |  573 | 1520287736 |
| 928829 |  573 | 1520287736 |
| 928830 |  573 | 1520287736 |
+--------+------+------------+
```

The table has now 4,134,798 rows and counting... and the records have 318 types and counting.
I'd like to create a report of the elapsed time for each type according to the timestamps. Every records means an activity of some type.

A report similar to:

```
type - elapsed time
573 - 3 days 4 hours 3 minutes
103 - 1 days 1 hours 1 minutes
```

I must walk through all the records adding the elapsed time between events  of some type, store the total elapsed time for some type of event and show the elapsed time by type.

Is someone willing to give me some insight?

This is my query:

```
SET @total = 0;
SET @curr_timestamp = 0;
SET @curr_id = 0;
SET @lineitem = 0;
SELECT CONCAT(FLOOR(HOUR(SEC_TO_TIME(Dedication)) / 24), ' días', ' ',TIME_FORMAT(SEC_TO_TIME(Dedication % (24 * 60 * 60)), '%H'), ' horas',' ',TIME_FORMAT(SEC_TO_TIME(Dedication % (24 * 60 * 60)), '%i'), ' minutos') As Dedicacion FROM
(
    SELECT type,
        (@lineitem:=@lineitem+1) line,
        (@prev_id:=@curr_id),
        (@curr_id:=id),
        (@prev_timestamp:=@curr_timestamp),
        (@curr_timestamp:=timestamp),
        (@newvalue:=IF(@prev_id>@curr_id,@prev_timestamp+@curr_timestamp,ABS(@prev_timestamp-@curr_timestamp))) newval,
        (@total:=@total+@newvalue) Dedication
    FROM mdl_logstore_standard_log WHERE (DATEDIFF(NOW(),FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp) ) < 7) AND type=573
) A WHERE line = @lineitem;
```

The query is based on this:

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/87159/how-to-calculate-a-total-by-comparing-current-and-next-row

Thanks,
Jorge Dávila.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your timestamp appears to be seconds as represented by Unix.  You can get the diff in seconds as:

```
select type, max(timestamp) - min(timestamp) as diff_in_seconds
from activities 
group by type;
```

Converting this to a time depends on the capabilities of the database you are using.  It is pretty easy to convert this to decimal days or hours.  For instance:

```
select type, (max(timestamp) - min(timestamp)) / (60 * 60) as diff_hours
from activities 
group by type;
```

Comment: Thank you very much Gordon Linoff but the max and min timestamps are not in the same row ... the values you are using are in differents rows. That values must be reached, added, stored, find the next pair, added the new sum to the total. Show the totals by type. The database is MySQL.

Comment: When I wrote my previous comment I had not executed the query ... I wonder why your query works. To show the elapsed time: CONCAT(FLOOR(HOUR(SEC_TO_TIME((max(timecreated)- min(timecreated)))) / 24), ' días', ' ',TIME_FORMAT(SEC_TO_TIME((max(timecreated)- min(timecreated)) % (24 * 60 * 60)), '%H'), ' horas',' ',TIME_FORMAT(SEC_TO_TIME((max(timecreated)- min(timecreated)) % (24 * 60 * 60)), '%i'), ' minutos'). Thank you very much. Jorge Dávila.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example how to accomplish what you want:

```
SELECT
    type,
    TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, MIN(timestamp), MAX(timestamp)) AS in_years,
    TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, MIN(timestamp), MAX(timestamp)) AS in_month,
    TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, MIN(timestamp), MAX(timestamp)) AS in_days,
    TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, MIN(timestamp), MAX(timestamp)) AS in_minutes,
    TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, MIN(timestamp), MAX(timestamp)) AS in_seconds
FROM
    activities
GROUP BY type
```

Comment: Michael, the query just return NULL values. The idea is adding the elapsed time between events to an total elapsed time by type of event. Your answer do not target the question but thanks. Jorge Dávila.

Comment: I would recommend adding your query to the OP so everyone can see exactly what you are doing